# Overwritten core functionality

Tags: module, magento-1, overrides

In Magento, we know that local modules can overwrite core functionality.  This is mainly done by using a rewrite rule in the config.xml.  My question is that since any module can do an overwrite, when developing, what is generally the best way to see for a given model or block what module is being used?  Can I get a final compiled list someplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently doing

Mage::log(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->xpath('//global//rewrite'));

at the very end of index.php may give me a full list of rewrites.